# Optimize code to minimize runtime of the macro

Tags: vba, excel

I have been writing some macros to perform some astrological calculations (calculating sign, lunar mansion, D9 & D60). The raw data is in the following format:

[image: input data format]

lng in the above image stands for longitude expressed in degree,minute,second format. The output has to be in the following format:

[image: output data layout]

I have whipped up the following code to read the data from the input sheet and format & copy it to the output sheet then do calculations with the longitude of each planet to calculate required fields.

```
Sub prepareOutput()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim c, count, d, l, ll
Dim r As Range
Set r = Worksheets("Ephemerides").Range("a4:" & Worksheets("Ephemerides").Range("a4").End(xlDown).Address)
Worksheets("output").Range("a3").Value = "Date"
For Each d In r
    Worksheets("output").Cells(d.Row, 1).Value = d.Value
Next

For Each c In Worksheets("Ephemerides").Range("d2:o2")
    If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
        count = count + 5
        'MsgBox count
        If count = 5 Then
            Worksheets("output").Cells(2, 2).Value = c.Value
            Worksheets("output").Cells(3, 2).Value = "Longitude"
            Worksheets("output").Cells(3, 3).Value = "Sign"
            Worksheets("output").Cells(3, 4).Value = "Nakshatra"
            Worksheets("output").Cells(3, 5).Value = "Navamsa"
            Worksheets("output").Cells(3, 6).Value = "D60"
            For Each l In Worksheets("Ephemerides").Range(c.Offset(2, 0), c.End(xlDown).Address)
                Worksheets("output").Cells(l.Row, 2).Value = l.Value
                Worksheets("output").Cells(l.Row, 3).Value = calcSign(l.Value)
            Next
            count = 2
        Else
            Worksheets("output").Cells(2, count).Value = c.Value
            Worksheets("output").Cells(3, count).Value = "Longitude"
            Worksheets("output").Cells(3, count + 1).Value = "Sign"
            Worksheets("output").Cells(3, count + 2).Value = "Nakshatra"
            Worksheets("output").Cells(3, count + 3).Value = "Navamsa"
            Worksheets("output").Cells(3, count + 4).Value = "D60"
            For Each ll In Worksheets("Ephemerides").Range(c.Offset(2, 0), c.End(xlDown).Address)
                Worksheets("output").Cells(ll.Row, count).Value = ll.Value
                Worksheets("output").Cells(ll.Row, count + 1).Value = calcSign(ll.Value)
            Next
        End If
    End If
Next
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub



Private Function deg2dec(deg As String) As Variant
d = Val(Mid(deg, 1, InStr(deg, "°") - 1))
m = Val(Mid(deg, InStr(deg, "°") + 1, 2)) / 100
deg2dec = d + m
End Function


Private Function calcSign(deg As String) As String
dec = deg2dec(deg)
Select Case dec
    Case 0 To 30
        calcSign = "Aries"
    Case 30 To 60
        calcSign = "Taurus"
    Case 60 To 90
        calcSign = "Gemini"
    Case 90 To 120
        calcSign = "Cancer"
    Case 120 To 150
        calcSign = "Leo"
    Case 150 To 180
        calcSign = "Virgo"
    Case 180 To 210
        calcSign = "Libra"
    Case 210 To 240
        calcSign = "Scorpio"
    Case 240 To 270
        calcSign = "Saggitarius"
    Case 270 To 300
        calcSign = "Capricorn"
    Case 300 To 330
        calcSign = "Aquarius"
    Case 330 To 360
        calcSign = "Pisces"
End Select
End Function
```

The above code doesn't calculate all 4 computed fields, just one for now.

The problem I am having is that I have 24000 rows and 12 columns in my input sheet and it is taking a lot of time to just copy this data to the output sheet and then doing calculations on it to compute one more value.And I have to calculate 3 more fields from one longitude value.

So if you guys could take a look at the code and let me know how i could go about minimizing the runtime here, that would help a lot.

Here's the link to the workbook if anyone wants to take a look. [astro.xlsm](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8OgQf1g9iFqWXVUU001ZFNKVWM/edit?usp=sharing)

Thanks in advance to all those who take out time to reply.

Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of things you can do. First of all, declaring all variable saves memory which in turn saves time. That being said, the real time consuming factor in your code is the looping through each cell. The fastest way to obtain the same result is to read the data into an array and then write the array to the output sheet. In the following code, I have edited your `prepareOutput` sub in such a way, that it keeps your initial code structure, but instead of looping through and writing to each cell, it now reads the data into an array and then writes this array to the desired output area.

```
Sub prepareOutput()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim c As Range, d As Range, l As Range, ll As Range, r As Range
    Dim count As Integer
    Dim ArrDim As Integer, CurrVal As Integer
    Dim OutRng As Range
    Dim TempArr() As String

    'Defines worksheets
    Dim WsEmph As Worksheet, WsOut As Worksheet
    Set WsEmph = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Ephemerides")
    Set WsOut = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Output")

    Set r = WsEmph.Range("a4:" & Worksheets("Ephemerides").Range("a4").End(xlDown).Address)

    WsOut.Range("a3").Value = "Date"
    For Each d In r
        WsOut.Cells(d.Row, 1).Value = d.Value
    Next

    For Each c In WsEmph.Range("d2:o2")
        If Not IsEmpty(c) Then
            count = count + 5

            'Redimension of temporary array
            ArrDim = WsEmph.Range(c.Offset(2, 0), c.End(xlDown)).Rows.count
            ReDim TempArr(1 To ArrDim, 1 To 2)
            CurrVal = 1

            If count = 5 Then
                With WsOut
                    .Cells(2, 2).Value = c.Value
                    .Cells(3, 2).Value = "Longitude"
                    .Cells(3, 3).Value = "Sign"
                    .Cells(3, 4).Value = "Nakshatra"
                    .Cells(3, 5).Value = "Navamsa"
                    .Cells(3, 6).Value = "D60"
                End With

                For Each l In WsEmph.Range(c.Offset(2, 0), c.End(xlDown).Address)
                    'Fills array
                    TempArr(CurrVal, 1) = l.Value
                    TempArr(CurrVal, 2) = calcSign(l.Value)
                    CurrVal = CurrVal + 1
                Next
                    'Sets output range and writes data
                    Set OutRng = WsOut.Range(WsOut.Cells(c.Offset(2, 0).Row, 2), WsOut.Cells(c.End(xlDown).Row, 3))
                    OutRng = TempArr
                    count = 2
            Else
                With WsOut
                    .Cells(2, count).Value = c.Value
                    .Cells(3, count).Value = "Longitude"
                    .Cells(3, count + 1).Value = "Sign"
                    .Cells(3, count + 2).Value = "Nakshatra"
                    .Cells(3, count + 3).Value = "Navamsa"
                    .Cells(3, count + 4).Value = "D60"
                End With

                For Each ll In WsEmph.Range(c.Offset(2, 0), c.End(xlDown).Address)
                    'Fills array
                    TempArr(CurrVal, 1) = ll.Value
                    TempArr(CurrVal, 2) = calcSign(ll.Value)
                    CurrVal = CurrVal + 1
                Next
                    'Sets output range and writes data
                    Set OutRng = WsOut.Range(WsOut.Cells(c.Offset(2, 0).Row, count), WsOut.Cells(c.End(xlDown).Row, count + 1))
                    OutRng = TempArr
            End If
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

On my system, running your code took ***25.16 seconds***. With the above changes to the code it now takes just ***3.16 seconds*** to perform the same task.

Note that I have also declared all variables and used worksheet-variables as refference to each worksheet. All though the latter doesn't improve speed, it only improves the readability of the code.

Comment: though SO says to avoid thanks and all, would like to thank you anyways for the working code. removed following two lines though, which i think are redundant.
WsOut.Cells(l.Row, 2).Value = l.Value
WsOut.Cells(l.Row, 3).Value = calcSign(l.Value)

Comment: No problem :) You are right - I forgot to remove those lines. I have removed the lines from the code too, and it accually improves the speed by one more second.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some tips that will make a huge difference to your code execution time:

1. Use `Option Explicit` and declare your variables as the most appropriate date type - only use `Variant` when you need to.
2. Store your data a numbers (not strings) and use cell format to display as you want
3. Don't loop over (large) ranges. Copy the range data to a variant array, and loop the array.  Copy the result back to the sheet at the end.  There is lots of examples of this on SO and elsewhere.

To display a number as Deg Minutes Seconds use number format `[h]°mm'ss\"` This leverages the time format, so you need to create the number value as `Deg/24 + Min/1440 + Sec/86400`  Eg `293°44'23"` has the value `12.2391550925926`