# Ideas to make this code more efficient

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet that lists a persons name (column A) with associated data (columns B through G).  I have code below that takes this list of a ~ 1000 rows that

A.) First copies and pastes each row three times (to create four identical rows for each entry) then

B.) Loops through the now ~4000 rows and creates a new worksheet for each person.

**As there are many duplicate names in column A this only creates ~ ten new worksheets**

The thing is, it runs but runs quite slowly (and I receive the Excel not responding warning at times).  Is there anything to clean this up to make it more efficient?  And after this I run another macro to save the new worksheets to a new workbook.  Would it be faster to do that with code here?

```
Sub Split_Data()

'This will split the data in column A out by unique values

    Const NameCol = "A"
    Const HeaderRow = 1
    Const FirstRow = 2
    Dim SrcSheet As Worksheet
    Dim TrgSheet As Worksheet
    Dim SrcRow As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim TrgRow As Long
    Dim person As String
    Dim lRow As Long
    Dim RepeatFactor As Variant

'Optimize Macro Speed
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

'Add four rows
    lRow = 2
    Do While (Cells(lRow, "B") <> "")
        RepeatFactor = 4

        Range(Cells(lRow, "A"), Cells(lRow, "G")).Copy
        Range(Cells(lRow + 1, "A"), Cells(lRow + RepeatFactor - 1, "G")).Select

        Selection.Insert Shift:=xlDown
        lRow = lRow + RepeatFactor - 1    
        lRow = lRow + 1
    Loop

    Set SrcSheet = ActiveSheet
    LastRow = SrcSheet.Cells(SrcSheet.Rows.Count, NameCol).End(xlUp).Row
    For SrcRow = FirstRow To LastRow
        person = SrcSheet.Cells(SrcRow, NameCol).Value
        Set TrgSheet = Nothing
        On Error Resume Next
        Set TrgSheet = Worksheets(person)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If TrgSheet Is Nothing Then
            Set TrgSheet = Worksheets.Add(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count))
            TrgSheet.Name = person
            SrcSheet.Rows(HeaderRow).Copy Destination:=TrgSheet.Rows(HeaderRow)
        End If
        TrgRow = TrgSheet.Cells(TrgSheet.Rows.Count, NameCol).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        SrcSheet.Rows(SrcRow).Copy Destination:=TrgSheet.Rows(TrgRow)
    Next SrcRow

ResetSettings:
  'Reset Macro Optimization Settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Wait a sec...Am I correctly understanding that this creates *~4000 new Worksheets*?  This sounds more like a fundamental design issue this isn't going to be solved by optimizing this particular `Sub`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optimize code to minimize runtime of the macro](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20716733/optimize-code-to-minimize-runtime-of-the-macro)

Comment: Please go to the [code review community](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @Comintern That's how I read it too. 4000 new worksheets in a single file is not a good idea. It's possible you are saying that 4000 new files get created (instead of worksheets in a single file, but that's not what the code says). Still not a good task for Excel VBA.

Comment: there is 4000 rows of data, the code checks to see if the worksheet for a person is already created so we can assume there are duplicate persons in the list.....I am sure the question otherwise would be "why is excel crashing when my code runs"

Comment: @comintern - There are at least 3000 duplicates in the list, so at most 1000 worksheets being created.  And that also means that the "splitting into new sheets" code could be improved by a factor of 4 by using a `Step 4` and copying four rows at a time (or by doing that step first and copying one row in the source sheet to 4 rows in the destination sheet).

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  There are duplicate persons in column A.  So it does not create that many new worksheets; the unique values for persons is ~ ten so it creates ~ ten new worksheets.   I can move this to the code review community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first you read the column of names in one pass and put it in an VBA array:

```
Dim DATA()
with SrcSheet
    DATA= .range(.cells(FirstRow, NameCol), .cells(lastRow, namecol)).value2
end with
```

this gives you a 2D array.
then you create a new scripiting.dictionary , wich fills on a for loop with DATA, and each time a name doesn't exist, you add it to the dictionary.

```
Dim Dict as new scripting.dictionary 'needs a reference in VBE to : Microsoft Scripting Runtime
dim i& 'long
dim h$ 'string 
for i=1 to lastrow-firstrow+1
    h=DATA(i,1)
    if not dict.exists(h) then
        dict(h)=i 'creaates an entry with key=h, item=whatever , here i
    end if
next i
```

You can either create the new worksheets on the fly while adding entries to Dict, or loop later `for i=1 to dict.count ...`

at the end , you reset all : `erase DATA : set Dict=nothing`.

Note that this code does not need error handling.

Plz comment on how much time this version needs to do the same task now.

EDIT : your `do while` looks slow (`copy select, insert`). If possible `B.value2=A.value2` from a range perspective.

Comment: Many thanks for the input.  I don't have experience with VBA arrays (quite new to this).  If I split the code into two subs (that is add four rows in one sub and then split the data into separate ws' in a second sub ) can you shed more light one of these actions would look when coded through an array?